# Invalid cross-thread access in WP7 after populating ObservableCollection within non UI thread

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, user-interface, asynchronous, dispatcher

I'm struggling with cross thread operations in WP7. Elements are successfully added do ObservableCollection but then nothing is displayed. Data binded ListBox (lBox) gives:

> Invalid cross-thread access.

Here is what I have:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> obrazkiFinal = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> ObrazkiFinal
    {
        get { return obrazkiFinal; }
        set { obrazkiFinal = value; }
    }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lBox.ItemsSource = ObrazkiFinal;

        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(@"http://website");
        IAsyncResult res = httpRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RespResult),httpRequest);
    }

    private void RespResult(IAsyncResult respResylt)
    {
        var res = (HttpWebRequest)respResylt.AsyncState;
        var resp = res.EndGetResponse(respResylt);

        /* some parsing code */
         foreach (/* found pic urls */)
         {
             //new httpwebrequest
             HttpWebRequest picHttpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(picUrl);
             IAsyncResult picRes = picHttpRequest.BeginGetResponse(DownloadImageResult, picHttpRequest );

       }

    private void DownloadImageResult(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var res = state.HttpWebRequest;
        var resp = res.EndGetResponse(result);

        /*some saving code*/

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { ObrazkiFinal.Add(fileName); });
     }
    }
}
```

And then in XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Name="lBox">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
              <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and of course in PhoneApplicationPage:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

ObservableCollection is succesfully populated within UI thread, so what's the matter?

@edit stack trace added:

> at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
>     at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp)
>     at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.GetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp)
>     at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
>     at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.get_ItemsSource()
>     at myPhoneApp.MainPage.DownloadImageResult(IAsyncResult result)
>     at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_8(Object state2)
>     at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>     at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
>     at System.Threading.Timer.ring()

Comment: It's not immediately obvious where your `fileName` variable comes from, so you've removed some code for brevity. Does any of this code modify the collection?

Comment: No, the only part modyfying collection is in DownloadImageResult(IAsyncResult result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your stack trace, the `DownloadImageResult` accesses the `ItemsSource` property of (I'm assuming) your `ListBox`. Remove this or move it to within a `BeginInvoke` block.

For more specific advice, please post the full content of your `DownloadImageResult` function.

Comment: Great, thanks for help. Everything was ok with ObservableCollection and ListBox. I was trying to access IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication(); outside Dispatcher.

Comment: @szysz3kster that doesn't sound like the real cause of the problem. Isolaed Storage is available from any thread, not just the UI one.